# Convergence of the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(\sin n)^n}{n}$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Please determine whether the series  $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(\sin n)^n}{n}$ converges.

(Note: In Mathematica, the result tends to converge. Moreover, this is a problem mis-copied from Advanced Calculus Exam, so we don't know the difficulty of the problem [Maybe it can be solved in college mathematics]. )

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level.

Comment: In fact, this is a problem in Advanced Calculus midtern exam, but mis-copied. So none of us successfully solve it. We've tried methods of basic convergence tests, Fourier series, all of which failed. But now we wonder any advanced way. By the way, should I remind others that this is a mis-copied question?

Comment: I'm not sure but I think you should try absolute convergence: take a small $\varepsilon$ and try to split the series' terms between those for which $\sin n \le \varepsilon$ and the others. The first series obviously converge by comparison to geometric series. And then for the other one, I'd try to major $\sin n$ by $1$ and try to major the series by $\sum \cfrac{1}{n^2}$. I'm not sure the second part can be done but if it can, I'd be with some kind of argument about $\sin$ that tells you the the number of terms in the partial sums of the second series is $O(\sqrt{n})$.

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT: This proof contains a mistake and I don't know if it can be saved (see the comments) - I'm leaving it up here in case it gives you an idea or if it can be corrected...**

---

I've managed to prove the (absolute!) convergence of the series based on an idea in the comment by user @xavierm02, but my proof uses a deep (and relatively modern) result in Diophantine approximation. It appears to me that since I use the deep result only to prove that something that appears negligible is indeed negligible, and I leave some degrees of freedom in that proof, I am optimistic that there is a more elementary way to do this part.

> **Lemma.** There is only a finite number of solutions to the inequality $\left| \sin n \right| > (\frac 1 2) ^{1/\sqrt n}$.

**Proof of Lemma**. I will skip some (I think simple) details in the proof. Let $\epsilon > 0$ be very small and observe the inequality $|\sin n| > 1-\epsilon$. Since $\sin$ is Lipschitz continuous and equal to $\pm 1$ exactly in the points $\pi/2 + \pi k$ for integers $k$ (and is symmetric around these points), there is some $\delta = \Theta(\epsilon)$ such that the above inequality is equivalent to: $|n - \pi/2 - \pi k| < \delta$. (That is, solutions are now in both $n$ and $k$.)

Dividing by $\pi n$ we get:

$$|\frac 1 \pi - \frac {2k+1} {2n}| < \frac \delta {\pi n}$$

This is a Diophantine approximation problem - how well can we approximate $1/\pi$ by rationals? Before we answer the question, let's plug in $\delta = \Theta(\epsilon)$ with the $\epsilon$ from the lemma. So up to some constant, we are interested in

$$|\frac 1 \pi - \frac {2k+1} {2n}| < \frac 1 n \left(1 - \left(\frac 1 2\right)^{1/\sqrt n} \right)$$

We now quote **Mahler's theorem [1953]: $1/\pi$ is not a [Liouville number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville_number)***, meaning rational approximations are only "polynomially good": Given a rational approximation $p/q \approx 1/\pi$, the difference $p/q - 1/\pi$ is bounded (below!) by some constant power of $q$. <s>However our Diophantine inequality requires a superpolynomial approximation, so it cannot be solved infinitely many times.</s> **Edit: This is wrong.**

<sub>* Actually, Mahler's theorem is about $\pi$, but Liouville numbers are closed under the reciprocal operation.</sub>

> **Proposition.** The series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac {(\sin n)^n} n$ converges absolutely.

**Proof.** All except a finite amount of values of $n$ satisfy $|\sin n|^n \le \left( \frac 1 2 \right)^{\sqrt n}$, which decays at least as fast as $1/n^3$. **QED.**

Comment: It's hard for me to grasp what your *superpolynomial approximation* means. Indeed, the right-hand side of the inequality just above the reference is of $\Theta(n^{-3/2})$, and in view of the fact that any irrationality measure of an irrational number satisfies $\geq 2$, the inequality is satisfied by infinitely many $n$'s.

Comment: Oh nooooo :( I've made a silly mistake, and treated $1−2^{-1/\sqrt n}$ as it it were $2^{-\sqrt n}$... Can this proof be saved?

Comment: Weaker versions of the lemma that might prove the proposition: (a) The amount of solutions to the inequality between a given $n$ and $2n$ is bounded by a constant. (Too strong?) (b) The amount of solutions up to $N$ is $O(N^{1-\epsilon})$, $\epsilon>0$.

Comment: Oh, I also considered the use of non-Liouvillian nature of $1/\pi$, but my lack of the detailed knowledge thwarted me from yielding any meaningful conclusion... :(